# Backup of Ubuntu dock launcher

Tags: backup, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Is there a way that I may backup the Ubuntu dock launcher?

I have Ubuntu 18.04, but I like to get Ubuntu 19.10. I want to keep all my settings and everything. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dconf dump` command to backup all the options for Ubuntu Dock as follows

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/
```

You can also save them to a file as follows

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/ > /path/to/ubuntu-dock.backup
```

(replace `/path/to/` by an actual proper path, you can also use any other name instead of `ubuntu-dock.backup`).

It is possible to restore the backed up options as follows

```
dconf load /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/ < /path/to/ubuntu-dock.backup
```

but however, I would not recommend it as you're most likely going to face an incompatibility issue as the versions of Ubuntu Dock in those two Ubuntu releases are not the same. Instead it would be more reasonable to carefully examine the differences between the options for a freshly installed Ubuntu release and the backed-up one and manually make changes accordingly.

Also, you can get the list of the *pinned* apps (added to favourites) by any of the following commands

```
dconf read /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
```

or

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

Comment: Thanks !  .... I will just wait until the next stable  LTS version of Ubuntu then.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not about LTS-vs-non-LTS btw. This would apply for the next LTS release too. The key point is the versions of the dock is different between the releases, so the idea of backing up settings from one version and blindly restoring in another version may lead to problems.

Comment: No Worries !  I just upgraded to 19.04 and it kept all my apps @ the dock. Only Ocenaudio is not running ...all my other apps are run great. This new update to 19.04 is much BETTER than 18.04  LOL